# VBA dates filter

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2013

easiest way to explain this is to use a example.
I have two dates(f.e.) "2014-08-08T8:11:31" and "2014-08-11T13:53:29".
I need to gave them proper form(date),exclude weekend(Saturday, Sunday ) and change it to working hours.I our case it's weekend and 2 hours for lunch - first day almost 8 hours(from 8 till 17) and second day almost 5 hours. Together 13 hours.
Input two dates 
output hours(or MD)

Answer (score 2):

The function `NETWORKDAYS` can calculate the number of working days between two dates. To convert from days to hours, we need to multiply that by 8.

Additional, you need to calculate the number of hours for the first day (the difference between 17 hour, or `17/24`-part of the day) and the last day (the difference between the finishing time and 8 o'clock, or `8/24`). Because we calculate the hours of the first and last day, we have to subtract 2 from the `NETWORKDAYS` answer.

So if your start date is in A1 and your end date in A2, your final function is: `=(NETWORKDAYS(A1;A2)-2)*8+17/24-MOD(A1;1)-8/24+MOD(A2;1)`.

Note that there is no checking on the sanity of the input data in the formula.